# Empty EKEventStore calendar list after authentication

Tags: swift, macos, ekevent

I would like to grab the names of my calendars on my Mac. I have 1 that's listed as "On My Mac", another (Birthdays) under "Other", and 4 that are pulled in from Google Calendar.

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
    eventStore.requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.event) { (accessGranted, error) in
    if (accessGranted) {
        let calendars = eventStore.calendars(for: .event)
        print(calendars)
    }
}
```

The goal is to determine how many days remain until the next event across all selected calendars.

Using the above code, I'm getting back an empty array. How can I access these calendars?

Comment: If the app is sandboxed have you enabled the entitlement to have access to Calendar?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your plist (i.e. Targets -> Info):

```
Privacy - Calendars Usage Description
```

Beside checking the `Calendars` box, Apple also requires a descriptive message for the permission dialog. It should explain why you need access to calendars.

iOS apps will crash without both, but Macs will fail silently.

Comment: The question implies that the `print` statement is showing an empty array. If your answer applied, wouldn't the `if` check fail since access wouldn't be granted?

Comment: Access is granted, but it won't go any further without the message. iOS will crash on build, but macOS will fail as described.